# Why does King Henry's "death" immediately place Thomas Cromwell in such danger?

Tags: plot-explanation, wolf-hall

In *Wolf Hall* episode 5, 'Crows', King Henry VIII suffers a fall at a joust and stops breathing. As panic ensues, young Rafe suggests to Thomas Cromwell that they flee before the ports are blockaded.

This proves to be unnecessary as the King recovers, but why does King Henry's apparent "death" immediately place Thomas Cromwell in such danger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume it's because of Thomas Cromwell's background. He came from a very [working class background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Cromwell#Early_life), born the son of a blacksmith. Many resented him for how far he rose in the King's court.

He was also known to have [great sway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Cromwell#Resistance_to_further_religious_reform) over the King and many other people in the court both feared and envied that.

If the King had died, it's highly unlikely Cromwell would have lived - more likely, he would have been executed.

Comment: Yes, Cromwell ruminates on the fact that his 'only friend is the King of England'. And of course even Cardinal Wolesey was mocked for his 'low birth'.